# Calling a function on a swf object in a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, swfobject

I'm making a Greasemonkey script which has to call some functions on a swf object. The script works fine in Chrome (with Tampermonkey), but in Firefox, using Greasemonkey, the function doesn't exist. When I try to log it, it shows up as undefined.

Is there some sort of extra security specifically in Firefox/Greasemonkey against calling functions on swfobjects? Any ways to get around it or disable it?

Comment: Without the code I'd guess you need to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) the function that accesses the object. Or maybe your script doesn't have the required `@grant` key. Or maybe you need to use `unsafeWindow` explicitly.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's a specific @grant that I need but I can't find any information about calling swfobject functions from greasemonkey anywhere. unsafeWindow should work I guess, that'll be my last resort.

The code is simple, I just go `$('#player object')[0].functionName()`, and I've made sure the jQuery call itself succeeds.

Comment: Yep, to call the functions defined by the remote page script you will need unsafeWindow and/or exporting of this code.